# Hidden/ReadOnly form values not posted to Action

Tags: iis, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-ajax

Hi Overflowers(with knowledge)

I have an issue with a .Net Core MVC site I just deployed.

I have a large input form with many components including multiple document upload and a dynamic grid.
I have a custom save button that sends the data to my action using Ajax and a submit button which uses the default form post.

Now both the save and submit buttons work correctly on my dev machine but as soon as I deploy to the web server the hidden and readonly fields on the form are not posted.

My dev machine is running IIS 10.0.10240 and the webs server is running IIS 8.5.9600.

Does anyone have an idea, as i said the Ajax and default post exclude these values on the hosted server but includes them on my dev machine.

**[Update]**

It would seem that it is not the readonly and hidden fields, but due to the fact that they are decimals and cannot be parsed to decimal data type?

e.g from model state:

"Lines[0645dc5b-09f8-4de5-ac0c-644a4103bcef].PriceExcl":{
      "ChildNodes":null,
      "Children":null,
      "Key":"Lines[0645dc5b-09f8-4de5-ac0c-644a4103bcef].PriceExcl",
      "SubKey":{
         "Buffer":"Lines[0645dc5b-09f8-4de5-ac0c-644a4103bcef].PriceExcl",
         "Offset":44,
         "Length":9,
         "Value":"PriceExcl",
         "HasValue":true
      },
      "IsContainerNode":false,
      "RawValue":"1437.50",
      "AttemptedValue":"1437.50",
      "Errors":[
         {
            "Exception":null,
            "ErrorMessage":"The value '1437.50' is not valid for PriceExcl."
         }
      ],
      "ValidationState":1
   }

Comment: Found my own solution and supplied the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few hour of head scratching i realized this was due to the model binder not binding the decimal values correctly. So i went ahead and create a custom model binder and attribute as seen here:

[.net core model binding](http://intellitect.com/custom-model-binding-in-asp-net-core-1-0/)